# How to integrate custom Python face recognition model in Flutter?

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, flutter, dart

I have a custom Python face recognition model. I want to integrate it locally in *Flutter* app so, how to integrate it in *Flutter*? To use it in *Flutter* do i have to convert it in some form like *tflite* or I can normally use it with some library?

Note- The model takes image as input and gives person info who's face the model recognizes. I want to integrate in *Flutter* so that it can run on mobile rather than on server.

Comment: You mean you're looking for a way to run python code in flutter, right?

Comment: @AliAlizadeh yes i have model ready and i want to integrate in flutter so that it can run on mobile rather than on server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [Firabase's machine learning functions](https://firebase.google.com), can be work better for mobile.

Comment: Your answer should be a comment and not an answer , as of stackoverflow's guidelines , so please make necessary updates to avoid down votes. Hope you understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut) plugin in order to run python code in a flutter application.